# What does ' '= ' ' mean

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from Employees where Name = 'John' or ''=''
```

This statement retrieves all employees in the table.

I couldn't understand how `''=''` is interpreted? Could you please explain?

Comment: is `''` equal to `''`?, the answer is yes, and since the condition is in an `OR`, the whole `WHERE` is true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`''=''` is always `true` since it's comparing two empty string

So essentially `''=''`  is a `Tautology` and moreover you are using an `OR` condition and thus your entire condition is always `true`. Your `WHERE` can also be written like

```
where Name = 'John' or 1 = 1
```

Your query can just be `select * from Employees` as the `WHERE` condition is of no effect.

Comment: I just searched something hard. It was simple enough. I couldn't see the point. Thanks

Comment: Good catch.  In case someone stumbles across this, "always" is not true in *all* databases -- this would be not-true in Oracle (alas).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that's strange to know but in `SQL Server` it's *always*

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty pointless `where` clause as it's searching for a name with:

```
where Name = 'John'
```

But it's also searching with an expression that always returns true:

```
or '' = ''
```

So all data would be returned regardless.

There should be no reason to include the second part unless this `where` clause is generated on the fly somewhere and the name filter is optional. Having the always true part included would prevent an error if names were not being filtered. Even still, I would question its use as it would return extra data.

If it is a generated `where` clause and it is required, it might be more logical to do:

```
or 1=2
```

Then you won't return extra data.